# Prove Schwarz inequality in $R^2$

Tags: integration, inequality

Can someone please show me how you would prove the following in $R^2$

$\int f(x)* g(x) dx  \leqslant \int f(x)^2 dx * \int g(x)^2 dx  $

starting from

$\int [\lambda*f(x) - g(x)]^2 dx  \geqslant  0$, where $\lambda$ is real

Also, can someone confirm that $\int f(x)^2 dx = \int f(x) dx \int f(x) dx$

Comment: Your last equality is false. Consider $f(x) = 1$ on the interval $[0, 2]$.

Comment: Maybe it would be slightly better to use $\cdot$ `$\cdot$` for multiplication (or simply omit the symbol for multiplication.) The symbol * is quite often used for [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution); this might be confusing for some readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $\int_{a}^{b}\left(\lambda f(x)-g(x)\right)^2dx\ge0$ for all $\lambda$, so

$\displaystyle\lambda^{2}\left(\int_{a}^{b}(f(x))^2dx\right)-2\lambda\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx\right)+\int_{a}^{b}(g(x))^2dx\ge0$ for all $\lambda$.

Therefore $b^2-4ac=\displaystyle4\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2-4\left(\int_{a}^{b}(f(x))^2dx\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}(g(x))^2dx\right)\le0$,

so $\;\;\;\displaystyle\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2\le\left(\int_{a}^{b}(f(x))^2dx\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}(g(x))^2dx\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you miss a square in the first inequality. (Tell me if i am wrong)(Since if $f= 1/2, g= 1/2 $ , on the interval [0,1], we would have $1/4 \leqslant 1/4 * 1/4$)

$\int [\lambda*f(x) - g(x)]^2 dx  \geqslant  0$, where $\lambda$ is real.

Then $\int \lambda^2f(x)^2 dx + \int g(x)^2dx \geqslant 2\int \lambda f(x) g(x)$, which is true for all real $\lambda$.

If the right hand side of the inequality is negative, take a negative $\lambda$ so that we can have $\int \lambda^2f(x)^2 dx + \int g(x)^2dx \geqslant 2\int \lambda f(x) g(x) \geqslant 0$.

Then we can square both side
$(\int \lambda^2 f(x)^2 dx)^2 + (\int g(x)^2 dx)^2 + 2 \int g(x)^2 dx * \int \lambda^2 f(x)^2 dx \geqslant 4 \lambda^2 (\int  f(x) g(x))^2  \geqslant 2 \lambda^2 (\int  f(x) g(x))^2 \geqslant 0$.

$2 \int g(x)^2dx * \int \lambda^2 f(x)^2 dx \geqslant 2 \lambda^2 (\int  f(x) g(x))^2$

Thus $ \int g(x)^2dx * \int f(x)^2 dx \geqslant  (\int  f(x) g(x))^2$

Comment: how did you justify the 2nd last inequality ?

Comment: @OBDA sorry i have made a terrible mistake